# dynamic list reading from file issues

Tags: c++, file, binary

```
struct list
{
    char town[30];
    int code;
    spisok *next,*head;
};

void reading(list *x)
{
    ifstream out("C:\\Users\\Tkachenko\\Desktop\\mp\\Lab_5\\file",ios::binary);
    if (out)
    {
        while(!out.eof())
        {
            out.read((char*)&x->town,sizeof(x->town));
            out.read((char*)&x->code,sizeof(x->code));
            x=x->next;
        }
        out.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "\n404 not found...";
}
```

I have issues with reading from a file. It writes additional lines that are repeats of previous lines. How can I fix that?

Comment: Common failure: Not testing the stream state (or an unformatted input). Please get informed.

Comment: i forgot add in cycle
cout << temp->town << "\t";
cout << temp->code << "\n";

Comment: Not the actual issue but never use `!eof` to control a loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: i guess that issue but when i add adittional logical function exmp while(!out.eof() && x!=0) it works but when i work in program, when i use this function first time it crash program guess this issue is because my list is not declared

Comment: @BogdanTkachenko ...or even *allocated*. Loading a linked list usually involves performing node allocations for the list *during* the load; not before.